# How to execute a binary file in memory in Ruby

Tags: ruby, memory, system

Is it possible to read binary in a Ruby file and execute it directly in memory?

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
x = IO.read('/bin/ls')
execute(x)
```

I tried `system(x)` but it returned:

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
```

Comment: Please add information about what you are trying to accomblish with this? Probably there is a better solution...

Comment: I just want to load program byte code and execute it from the memory instead of the hard disk. It's similar to system() and exec() but I want to do the same by passing the program loaded in memory to the system instead the hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

`system()` and `exec()` both pass the command string to the OS to have it load and launch an external command, which isn't what you're asking to do.

For instance, this is from the `system()` documentation:

```
Executes command... in a subshell.
command... is one of following forms.

commandline:
  command line string which is passed to the standard shell

cmdname, arg1, ...:
  command name and one or more arguments (no shell)

[cmdname, argv0], arg1, ...:
  command name, argv[0] and zero or more arguments (no shell)
```

Something could probably be written in C, as that is how Ruby is extended. There is [lots of information](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=extend+ruby+with+c&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to do that. When an executable starts, the dynamic linker needs to do quite a lot of fixing links up.

The simplest solution is to write the executable to a temporary disk file somewhere, and execute that.

Comment: can't we do something similar to eval() but for byte code or asm code?